# Determining boundary of basins of attraction

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Let's say that I have a dynamical system that displays multiple stable states with corresponding basins of attraction. The Lyapunov function for the system is not known.

Is there an analytic or semi-analytic method to locate the edges of basins, ie where one basin ends and another begins? In a system that has many such basins, there might be special points where several basins meet (I'm thinking of points at which very small changes in initial conditions can leave the system in one of several possible equilibrium states). Is there anything I can do here given that I don't explicitly know the Lyapunov function?

My system doesn't have fractal basin boundaries or anything unusual like that. It's a system of four dependent variables as well as time.

Thank you!

Comment: 1. In what dimension lives your system? 2. Could you provide an example? My current understanding of subject is that basins of attraction never can intersect (it follows from conventional definition of attractor). However, finding the boundary is interesting task (because it's invariant and has its own dynamics).

Comment: @Evgeny Yes of course, I have edited the question in order to remove the troublesome phrase "intersections," as well as some additional information. I'm still working on making a minimal working example.

Comment: In some systems (like 1 degree of freedom Hamiltonian system) it's possible to find separatrices (semi)analytically and to rule out boundaries of different basins (it could be done via the analysis of Hamiltonian level sets). General 2D plane case also has separatrices as part of boundaries, but it's much harder to find them analytically. I can't say anything useful in higher dimensional case..

Comment: I agree, but isn't that because the Hamiltonian is pretty much the Lyapunov function? Or maybe, more generally, Lyapunov functions are like generalized Hamiltonians. The tricky thing is that my system isn't explicitly derived from a scalar field, so if I wanted to make one I have to use trial-and-error to build one.

Comment: One of my scientific advisors once had a joke that Lyapunov function and Hamiltonian dynamics are *quite orthogonal* (pun intended). They are similar in the sense that one function can tell a lot (or almost everything) about dynamics, but Hamiltonian restricts trajectories to its level sets and Lyapunov function tells how trajectories slide to local minima along its level sets.

Comment: I see, so perhaps the Lyapunov function is more analogous to just the effective potential portion of the Hamiltonian? I'm actually curious now if there's a hard analogy to be made here, that might give me some better intuition.

Comment: Perhaps. If you imagine local Lyapunov function as some sort of "landscape" around steady state then trajectories just go to the minima of that "pit".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no -- there is no such general method in dimension >2. Sometimes you can compute one-dimensional separatrices using Melnikov methods, but nothing more. There are also numerical techinques but analysis could be done only for some very specific systems.

Usually you can not determine even one single domain of attraction analytically.